# Type annotation for an iterable class

Tags: python, typing

I've got a class that extends `ElementTree.Element`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from typing import cast


class MyElement(ET.Element):
    def my_method(self):
        print('OK')


xml = '''<test> <sub/> <sub/> </test>'''

root: MyElement = cast(
    MyElement,
    ET.fromstring(xml, parser=ET.XMLParser(target=ET.TreeBuilder(element_factory=MyElement))))

root.my_method()  # this is fine

for ch in root:
    ch.my_method()  # PyCharm error message  ???
```

This does work, however the last line is highlighted by PyCharm because it considers `ch` to be `Element`, not `MyElement`.

How should I annotate `MyElement` to make it clear that when I iterate it, I get `MyElement` instances and not `ET.Element`s?

Comment: Do you actually have any guarantee that what you get from iterable is not gonna be `Element`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotate the `__iter__` of `MyElement` as a method to return `Iterator[MyElement]`. There is almost no additional runtime overhead. Pycharm and mypy will both pass:

```
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator


class MyElement(ET.Element):
    def my_method(self):
        print('OK')

    __iter__: Callable[..., Iterator['MyElement']]
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of workarounds

#### 1. Annotation cheese

There is a somewhat cheesy trick that doesn't violate any syntax: annotating variable before the loop.

```
ch: MyElement
for ch in root:
    ch.my_method()
```

https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed

You can't annotate inside the for loop but can do so before it.

#### 2. Override methods

You can add overridden methods for `__iter__` and `__next__` for your `MyElement` class with annotations:

```
def __iter__(self) -> MyElement:
    return super().iter()

def __next__(self) -> MyElement:
    pass
```

`Element` parent doesn't have `__iter__` or `__next__` natively so it's a bit sketchy but I didn't want to spend more time researching it so "posted as is because it worked"™ They were both required for the annotation to work. Also for prerequisites you will need to import

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

in the beginning of your script to access `-> MyElement` inside itself without issues.

Comment: thanks, but I have lots of `for` loops and annotating each one is out of the question.

Comment: I included a secondary option in the answer, if that's something more easily approachable in your project

Comment: BTW, your annotation (first) solution won't narrow type and will keep raising smth like `cannot assign value of type Element to variable of type MyElement [assignment]`. You can `assert isinstance(...)` or `cast` in loop body to avoid it.

Comment: well, the second idea looks viable, however `iter()` won't work here